# Copying data from one excel workbook to another using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook which I am working with. I need to import data from another workbook. The first workbook is called MyBook.xls and second one is called protfolioData.xls. The path to protfolio data is in the cell D12. How can I create a vbscript that takes the path form D12 and copies data in cells A4:D26 from protfolio data and create a newSheet in MyBook.xls. I am currently trying the following, it throws an error ambigous name when macro is run from MyBook.xls.

```
    ext_file = Workbooks(mainFile).Worksheets("config").Range("D12").Value
    Workbooks(ext_file).Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("4:26").Copy _
    Workbooks(mainFile).Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("1:22")
```

Comment: For starters, Rows("4:26") is 23 rows; Rows("1:22") is 22 rows.

Comment: Fixed this, but still not working

Comment: Check the spelling of `protfolioData` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe Try the following code :

```
    Sub test()

        'Get the Path
        ext_file = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("config").Range("D12").Value

        'Get the workbook name from the path
        GetFileName = Right(ext_file, Len(ext_file) - InStrRev(ext_file, "\"))

        'open and activate the workbook
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ext_file
        Workbooks(GetFileName).Activate

        'Add new sheet to thisworkbook ( MyBook.xls )
        With ThisWorkbook
            Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        End With

        'Copy rows 4 to 26 from protfolioData.xls and paste in rows 1 to 23 in ( MyBook.xls )
        Workbooks(GetFileName).Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("4:26").Copy _
        Destination:=ws.Rows("1:23")

        'close protfolioData.xls
        Workbooks(GetFileName).Close savechanges:=False


    End Sub
```